# Invalid format for email address in WordPress on Azure app service

Tags: wordpress, azure, email, azure-web-app-service

I am new to WordPress and Azure. There are two mail was setup in WordPress on Azure app service. one mail was failed. one mail was successful. "Your submission failed because of a server error" is the error message that appears.

I don't know how to  test mail in WordPress. please help me to how to do this